# Control.Lens lens for a total map

Tags: haskell, lenses, haskell-lens

I have a total map from type A to type B.

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Maybe

tmGet k m = fromJust $ M.lookup k m

tmSet k v = M.insert k v
```

I used `Data.Map` as an example implementation but it can be anything, e.g. an `Array` or even a `Bool`-indexed tuple:

```
tmGet True  = fst
tmGet False = snd
```

I want to have a `tmAt` function to construct a lens:

```
(42, 665) ^. tmAt True == 42
(42, 665) & tmAt False +~ 1 == (42, 666)
```

The question is how do I construct `tmAt` out of `tmGet` and `tmSet` (or `tmModify`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation for the Control.Lens module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.9.0.2/docs/Control-Lens.html) there's a very handy image of different parts of the *lens* package. Since you want to construct a `Lens`, you can look at the `Lens` part of the diagram. The topmost function shown is

```
lens :: (s -> a) -> (s -> b -> t) -> Lens s t a b
```

This constructs a Lens from a getter and a setter.

The function `s -> a` is a getter – the type signature means, "If you give me a data structure `s`, I will pick an `a` value out of it." The `s -> b -> t` function is the setter, and the type signature means, "If you give me an `s` and a new value `b`, I will create for you a new structure `t`." (The types are different because lenses can actually change types of things.)

If your getter is `tmGet` and your setter is `tmSet`, you can therefore construct a lens with

```
tmAt :: Boolean -> Lens s t a b
tmAt b = lens (tmGet b) (tmSet b)
```

for whatever your actual `s`, `t`, `a`, and `b` parameters are. In the example of a tuple, it would be

```
tmAt :: Bool -> Lens (a, a) (a, a) a a
```

(In other words, if you give the Lens a function `a -> a`, it can transform an `(a, a)`-tuple into another `(a, a)`-tuple.)

---

If you want to be fancy, you can also rewrite `tmAt` as

```
tmAt = lens <$> tmGet <*> tmSet
```

Comment: Ha, that Applicative form is nice

Answer (score 0):

Once you have defined `tmGet` and `tmSet` to be of type

```
tmGet :: k -> f v -> v
tmSet :: k -> f v -> v -> f v
```

you can defined a family of lenses by feeding the lens constructor `lens` with your parameterized getters and setters. Here's how you would do it for a pair indexed by a `Bool`

```
tmGet True  = fst
tmGet False = snd

tmSet True  (_,b) a = (a,b)
tmSet False (a,_) b = (a,b)

tmAt b = lens (tmGet b) (tmSet b)
```

Now in GHCI

```
>>> (42,665) ^. tmAt True
42
>>> (42,665) & tmAt False +~ 1
(42,666)
```